# Why is IMemoryCache's TryGetValue throwing an InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-core

In my Web application, I have one of my services that uses an injected `IMemoryCache`:

```
public class InternalService
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache m_memoryCache;

    private readonly MemoryCacheEntryOptions m_cacheEntryOptions;

    public Service(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
         m_memoryCache = memoryCache;

         // Set cache options: keep in cache for this time, reset time in 1 hour, no matter what.
        m_cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(1d));
    }
}
```

In this service, I am using the cache to avoid an expensive call. The call returns a list of Entity:

```
public class Entity
{
    public long Id {get; set;}    
}
```

Here is the method in the Service that deals with the cache:

```
private async IList<Entity> GetEntitiesAsync(string tenantId)
{
    if (false == m_memoryCache.TryGetValue(tenantId, out IList<Entity> tenantEntities) || tenantEntities.Count == 0)
    {
         // Do the expensive call.
         IList<Entity> tenantEntities = await ExpensiveServiceCallAsync(tenantId);

         m_memoryCache.Set(tenantId, tenantEntities , m_cacheEntryOptions);
    }

    return tenantEntities;
}
```

However, it does throw the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Entity]'. 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.CacheExtensions.TryGetValue[TItem](IMemoryCache
>   cache, Object key, TItem& value)

As specified in the Microsoft documentation, it says that :

> The in-memory cache can store any object; the distributed cache
>   interface is limited to byte[].

**Question**

What am I doing wrong? I do not understand why the cache is expecting to return a `string` when I was supposed to cache a list of `Entity`.

Comment: Just checking, in your constructor you set your local variable of m_memoryCache but in your GetEntitiesAsync method you use m_cache. Is this just a typo?

Comment: I've got a suspicion that somewhere in your code you are adding a string value to the cache with the same tenantId you are using here.

Comment: Correct. This is indeed just a copy-paste mistake.

Comment: Perhaps try if (false == m_memoryCache.TryGetValue(tenantId, out object tenantEntities) and see what comes back from cache

Comment: You are correct... I did not realize that another class in our application was using the cache and the same key to store its own information... which turns out is another string. Could you post this as an answer?

Comment: Great, will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a suspicion that somewhere in your code you are adding a `string` value to the cache with the same `tenantId` that you are using here.

Remember, that `m_memoryCache` instance is used throughout your code.